# How can I convert this Python code into ColdFusion code?

Tags: python, sql, coldfusion, railo

I am looking to build a web application that utilizes the Reddit (open source) algorithm.

I plan to tweak it over time but for now I think it'll be a good start to use their ranking system.

I read a blog post about this algorithm and the example is written in Python. How can I convert this for use in ColdFusion? Additional bonus points for usage in a CFC if it's easier?

The code:

```
#Rewritten code from /r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import log

epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)

def epoch_seconds(date):
    """Returns the number of seconds from the epoch to date."""
    td = date - epoch
    return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)

def score(ups, downs):
    return ups - downs

def hot(ups, downs, date):
    """The hot formula. Should match the equivalent function in postgres."""
    s = score(ups, downs)
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(order + sign * seconds / 45000, 7)
```

The blog post that talks about this code:
http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

Looking forward to hearing some ideas and examples.

Many thanks!
Michael.

Also, as an additional question; would this code be better performed via an SQL query or some kind of sorting in ColdFusion *after* the data-set has already been collected? My DB of choice would be MySQL.

**UPDATE:**
Just found another question on here that relates to what I was asking...I think it helps.
[How are Reddit and Hacker News ranking algorithms used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262224/how-are-reddit-and-hacker-news-ranking-algorithms-used)

Answer (score 6):

Most of that code is just standard code from any programming language

For example to get the seconds since a certain date is pretty easy in ColdFusion

```
<cfset seconds = dateDiff('s', now(), createDate(1970, 1, 1)) />
```

Not sure which bits your stuck with, but its all prety simple. Every function I see there has a ColdFusion version and without just wanting someone to rewrite it for you, I suggest you try to do it and ask if you get stuck with something.

Comment: I'd just like to ask; is this something best done in SQL or would sorting in CF after the data-set has already been collected be the best option? Thanks for your input by the way - really helping.

Comment: That would depend on whether the sort would be used in some other place.  If that is the case, then probably putting in a CF function would be preferable to in the SQL.

Comment: This question could be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com